# Remove torrent files from specific tracker

Tags: bittorrent

My favorite bittorrent tracker just went down for good after a long run, and now I'd like to do some cleanup -- specifically I want to purge the 2000 or so torrent files from just that tracker out of my torrents directory.  I can write a perl script to run a tool like aria2c and then parse the output for the Announce field, but that seems overly complicated.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and wrote a script to do this.  It's a little fussy because torrent file names frequently contain spaces and other unix-unfriendly characters, but it works.  I'm using transmission-show to read the torrent files because it comes loaded with my client, but you could look at the answers to "is there a tool to view a torrent file?" for a list of other tools.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@files = `ls -1`;
for(@files){
  chomp;
  $current = $_;
  $out = `transmission-show "$current"`;
  if($out =~ /INSERT\.TRACKER\.HERE/){
    system("mv \"$current\" ../destination_folder");
  }
}
```

Be sure to create a backup of your torrents directory first